# Error saving interaction model - Bad request on Alexa Skills Builder

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am working on a alexa skill and on Alexa skills builder I can't save / build my skill with a Intent slot (Answer for a Trivia Skill) all I get is when I try is ***Error saving interaction model
Bad request*** If I remove the custom intent slot (Answer) it works perfectly fine. Is this error from my side or is it a Skills Builder error?

Thanks

Anush.

Comment: Can you please share your custom slots, interaction model, and utterances?

Comment: Hi , The error was fixed by itself! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the code from here https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-trivia try copying and pasting the json from one of the interaction models in the ./models folder into the "code editor" in the Skill Builder. It's likely just a minor typo in the json.

Comment: I will tey that out today Steve!

Comment: Hey Steve, The interaction model  was built without modification two days later? must of been a error on amazons side

Comment: Whatever it was, I'm glad to hear it's resolved Anush.